# Understanding the free memory usage output

Tags: memory-management, net-snmp

I am using free command to check the memory in detail and getting sufficient available memory i.e. 33030404 KB.
But while monitoring memory by SNMP tool I am getting insufficient memory i.e. 887364 KB.
I have created a memory watchdog on the basis of output from SNMP command which leads to false positives.

**SNMP output:** -

```
Total Memory: **Available Memory**: Buffer Memory: Cache Memory: Free Memory:
42131956      **887364**            371308         3028580       2842500
```

**Free: -**

```
total    used     **free**   shared  buff/cache **available**
42131956 36668700 **886252** 202952  4577004    **33030404**

Swap: 2195452 240316 1955136
```

Can anyone explain,

1. Why there is a huge difference in Available memory of both commands.(SNMP & free command) ?
2. In free command, as per the above example, free memory is: **886252** KB and available memory is:
   **33030404** KB, which is again a huge difference.
   Due to this output, SNMP monitoring tool is always sending memory
   alerts.

**Free: -**

```
total    used     **free**   shared  buff/cache **available**
42131956 36668700 **886252** 202952  4577004    **33030404**

Swap: 2195452 240316 1955136
```

I am expecting below o/p or something similar in terms of free field.

**Free: -**

```
total    used     **free**   shared  buff/cache **available**
42131956 36668700 **33030404** 202952  4577004    **33030404**

Swap: 2195452 240316 1955136
```

Regards,
bnaigaonkar

Comment: Here, I am suspecting on SNMP memory management calculation, but not sure. Any help is much appreciated.